# Mockito stubbing - returning a repeat value X number of times

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I know that by creating a stub in Mockito, consecutive values can be returned from a mock like so:

```
when(mockedObject.doSomething()).thenReturn(1, 1, 1, 1, 5);
```

or

```
when(mockedObject.doSomething()).thenReturn(1).thenReturn(1).thenReturn(1).thenReturn(1).thenReturn(5);
```

Is it possible to specify a repeat number for a specific return value? Something like this:

```
when(mockedObject.doSomething()).thenReturn(1, times(4)).thenReturn(5);
```

Comment: The arguments to `thenReturn` are the first value, followed by a varargs of the subsequent values.  So you could pass an array consisting of the subsequent values as the second argument.  And of course, you could build that array using calls to `Arrays.fill`.

Comment: Or you can keep a reference to the OngoingStubbing and use a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
class Mockme {
    @Test
    void test() {
        final UnderTest mock = Mockito.mock(UnderTest.class);
        OngoingStubbing<Integer> stubbing = Mockito.when(mock.get());

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            stubbing = stubbing.thenReturn(1);
        }

        stubbing.thenReturn(5, 7, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(mock.get());
        }
    }
}

interface UnderTest {
    int get();
}
```

Or a pre-computed array, but `thenReturn` expects the first return value as a separate argument, so this will be difficult to maintain:

```
@Test
void test() {
    final Integer[] returns = new Integer[6];
    Arrays.fill(returns, 1);
    returns[3] = 5;
    returns[4] = 7;
    returns[5] = 10;

    final UnderTest mock = Mockito.mock(UnderTest.class);
    Mockito.when(mock.get()).thenReturn(1, returns);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(mock.get());
    }
}
```